# Trouble Installing Rails in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, installation

I used VMWare to open and install Ubuntu (64-bit 14.04.1) .iso file. I started Ubuntu, and now I'm installing rails in the virtual machines. When I rain this command:

`bash < <(curl -sL https://raw.github.com/railsgirls/installation-scripts/master/rails-install-ubuntu.sh)`

I get this: `sudo: apt-get: command not found`

I have ruby 2.2.0 and Homebrew installed. What am I missing? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is nothing to to with Rails, Ruby, Homebrew - it's the basic Ubuntu package manager, [this question from StackExchange's Ubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/q/77957) should help.